# How to align a view bottom trailing, overlaid on another view that clips over the edge of the screen in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, background, alignment

I have a view which consists of a background image/animation and a foreground control buttons. I want to `.overlay` the buttons on top of the background, to be aligned at the bottom leading, center, and trailing - see screenshot below (doesn't show the actual background).

However, the background has to be an animation. I'm using a wrapper view around `AVPlayer` for this. The video that gets played is portrait, but it gets filled to landscape as is thus wider than screen. I need it to fill the vertical space of the screen. That means that I have to use `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).scaledToFill()`.

That leaves vertical alignment just fine - the gray top-center badge and the bottom-center button are rendered at the right places - however, it messes with the horizontal alignment. The bottom-right button aligns itself w.r.t. the video instead of the screen, and is thus aligned out of the bounds of the screen (see the second image).

I need the background to fill the screen, and the overlay to be aligned properly. The videos are recorded portrait, but `AVPlayer` makes them landscape with black filling on the sides, so unless that can be tweaked, I can't change the videos' aspect-ratios.

The most beneficial thing for me would be to learn how to **align components w.r.t. the screen**, not the parent in the overlay stack. Is there are way to achieve that? If not, is there a workaround to fix my problem (make the buttons align properly along the horizontal)?

## Code

The code below isn't the source of truth, and just generates the demos. It is provided since a gentleman in the comments politely asked for it. The images are the ultimate source of truth. The actual code is much bigger, with a mechanism of randomly (and based on app state) choosing an `AVPlayer` to play an `mp4` video. I don't think that this should be important (encapsulation and stuff), but if it is, tell me why it affects the code structure in the comments, and I will add more details.

A function used in the demos below is:

```swift
private func bigBgImage() -> some View {
    self.backgroundChooser.render()
        .resizable()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .scaledToFill()
}
```

...where `backgroundChooser.render()` is to be taken as a blackbox. You can just drop in a dummy `Image`.

### Desired layout

[image: desired overlay layout]

This demo is achieved through a dummy image in a `GeometryReader`. This is a workaround to bound the overlays despite the `bigBgImage` having `maxWidth: .infinity`. Since `GeometryReader` messes with the animation alignment, I don't want to use it in the final code. Nevertheless, here's the snippet:

```swift
GeometryReader { _ in
    self.bigBgImage()
}
    .overlay(alignment: .top) { self.title() }
    .overlay(alignment: .bottom) { self.resetButton() }
    .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) { self.toggleButton() }
```

### Undesired layout

[image: overflow messes up horizontal align]

```swift
self.bigBgImage()
    .overlay(alignment: .top) { self.title() }
    .overlay(alignment: .bottom) { self.resetButton() }
    .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) { self.toggleButton() }
```

The mechanism behind `backgroundChooser` is too complex to contain in an SO question in a meaningful way. One can just drop in any image

Comment: The pictures are nice and all, but code of your view would be nicer.

Comment: I don't get why you need to ask for it in such a salty way (cf. your bio). The pictures are descriptive of the behaviour enough - in fact, they describe the behaviour better than what I can reliably code up, which is **why I'm asking this question in the first place**. I will add rough snippets, but they're not the source of truth - the pictures are (whether you like it or not).

Comment: Having 3 buttons to be at the bottom part of the screen as leading, center, trailing is what you wanted right?

Comment: @tail Yes, three action buttons. For the purposes of this question, the count doesn't matter - the problem is with the leading/trailing alignment in the presence of a `maxWidth: .infinity` clipping-over-the-edge underlying view. See @Asperi's answer for how to make the buttons align properly (use a dummy view with `background` and `overlay`). This breaks the alignment of the background, which I've only been able to resolve with a workaround - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a workaround involving manually setting an `x` offset for the background.

Building on [Asperi's partial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73181191/3835692), we add a `GeometryReader` and `offset` the `background` by half the width:

```swift
Color.clear
     .background() {
         GeometryReader { geo in
             self.bigBgImage()
                 .offset(x: -geo.size.width / 2)
         }
     }
     .overlay(alignment: .top) { self.title() }
     .overlay(alignment: .bottom) { self.resetButton() }
     .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) { self.toggleButton() }
```

Answer (score 3):

In this scenario we should separate controls from content. A possible approach is to have independent screen layer (bound always to screen geometry), then move content into background, and controls into overlays, like

```
Color.clear    // << always tight to screen area
//.ignoresSafeArea() // << optional, if needed

  .background(self.bigBgImage()) // now independent, but not clipped

  .overlay(alignment: .top) { self.title() }          // << all on screen
  .overlay(alignment: .bottom) { self.resetButton() }
  .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) { self.toggleButton() }
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I didn't know about `.background`. This however also messes with the alignment. The video is recorded in portrait mode, but `AVPlayerViewController` makes it into landscape by padding with black edges on the left and right. This makes the video align on the left edge and clipping on the right edge. Is there a way to make it clip evenly on both edges, so as to make it centered?

Comment: Well, this doesn't answer the question, since it's specified that the background is a video that has to clip over the screen bounds. I believe that a background view with overlay action buttons is such a prevalent design pattern in mobile applications, that anyone experienced with a given UI framework can work out the design in no time (I started using SwiftUI yesterday, been able to google the stuff in 10mins). The crux of the question is the interaction of clipping, overlay and alignment - which you don't address.

Answer (score 3):

I found that the problem was your `.frame` and `.scaleToFill()` after the **Image**.

Here I have a different solution. (Code is below the image)
[image]

Use screen max width and height instead of .infinity with overlay

```
struct DemoView: View {
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        bigBigImage
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                Button("Top") {
                }
                .padding()
                .background(.black)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                Button("Center") {
                }
                .padding()
                .background(.black)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                Button("Leading") {
                }
                .padding()
                .background(.black)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.trailing)
            }
     }
   }
    var bigBigImage: some View {
     Image("Swift")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill() //here
        .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, maxHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.height) //here
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for another option! I am unsure if this won't make the video too small (since it's force landscape), but I will try it. I've reworked the video controller a bit, so I can't check it now.